# Blog statistics

Tags: statistics

I run small wordpress blog with 3-5 users. People add/edit/remove and read content all the time... What I want is to be able to see some sort of statistics.... which posts/pages are most popular, most updated, commented... which external links are the ones clicked most times... etc....

is there a plugin (not external service) to achieve that?

Comment: The blog is self hosted and private... no third party company should have ANY access to it

Comment: something like WordPress.com Stats http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/stats/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Piwik](http://piwik.org/) is similar to Google Analytics, but you install on your own server.

Also- I've seen a private internal intranet site that was tracked on Google Analytics. It was certainly not publicly or search engine accessible, so it is possible to at least use GA on a private site if you're curious to investigate further.